# Column Alignment After Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jeditable, datatables

Im using [Datatables](http://datatables.net) in my c# MVC4 application.  One of my tables is using jeditable to allow the user to double click any cell in a table, make changes to the value in that cell, and then upon clicking enter save changes to the database which remain reflected on the screen.

The problem is that after changing a value, the column alignment goes haywire and a column's data may show as much as 4,5,or 6 columns lengths to the right of the header that it pertains to.

Here is the script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable1 = $('#BodyTable').dataTable({
            sScrollX: "100%",
            sScrollY: "200px",
            bFilter: false,
            bScrollCollapse: true,
            bPaginate: false,
            bScrollInfinite: true,
            bSort: false,
            //iScrollLoadGap: 10,
            oLanguage: {
                sZeroRecords: "There are no records that match your search criterion"
            }
        }).makeEditable({ sUpdateURL: '@Url.Action("UpdateData", "Home")',});
```

ActionResult:

```
public string UpdateData(string id, string value, int? rowId, int? columnPosition, int? columnId, string columnName)
    {
        PViewModel H = new PViewModel();
        H.UpdateSValue(Convert.ToInt32(rowId), columnName, value, id);
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: How are you updating the row after editing the data? DataTables has specific methods built in for updating the row's underlying data. See `fnUpdate`. If you're manually inserting rows (or jeditable is..not familiar with that plugin) then you could easily end up with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on window resizes. Check out

http://datatables.net/api#fnAdjustColumnSizing

That will resize the columns to fit correctly.